# Unit testing Polymer listener that uses this.fire

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a Polymer element that is set up something like this:

```
Polymer({

  is: 'some-element',


  properties: {
    //properties
  },

  listeners: {
    'something-happened': '_onSomethingHappening'
  },
  someFunction: function() {},

  anotherFunction: function() { // something-happened listener is executed here},

  _onSomethingHappening: function(e) {
      this.fire('it-happened', {e.someInfo});
  }
})
```

I have unit tested all functions, but I need to test for the _onSomethingHappening event. I try to capture the return value of the this.fire event, but this doesn't work. The unit test I have in mind is something like this:

```
test('_onSomethingHappened', function() {

    var ev = some-element._onSomethingHappened();
    assert(typeof ev, 'object');

});
```

The thing is, when I do this, it says that no event was passed to the listener, so therefore the test fails. Is there a way I could structure this test to make it work? Is there a way to say "assert that a JS .fire event was executed"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [Web Component Tester](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester), you could use a [SinonJS spy](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies) on your test fixture's `fire` method, and assert that it was called with specific parameters.

*test.html:*

```
<test-fixture id="basic">
  <template>
    <my-list></my-list>
  </template>
</test-fixture>

<script>
  describe('my-list', function() {
    var list;

    beforeEach(function() {
      list = fixture('basic');
    });

    it('fires "foo" event with {bar: xxx}', function() {
      sinon.spy(list, 'fire');

      var e = {someInfo: 100};
      list._onSomethingHappened(e);
      expect(list.fire).to.have.been.calledWith('foo', {bar: e.someInfo});
    });
  });
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could test that the element emitted the event.

```
describe('my-list', function() {
  ...
  it('emits "foo" event with {bar: xxx}', function() {
    list._onTestFoo = sinon.spy();
    list.listen(list, 'foo', '_onTestFoo');

    var e = {someInfo: 100};
    list._onSomethingHappened(e);
    expect(list._onTestFoo).to.have.been.called;
    expect(list._onTestFoo.args[0][0].detail).to.deep.equal({bar: e.someInfo});
  });
});
```

The [Polymer Test Guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/tools/tests.html) and Polymer Starter Kit's [test/my-list-basic.html](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/0c3c065/app/test/my-list-basic.html) could be helpful as a starting point.